# GLfloat or GLdouble by default?

Tags: c++, opengl

In C++, it is better to use `double` by default and `float` or `long double` only when we really know we need them. For OpenGL though, I see that `GLfloat` seems to be the default. Is it still pertinent considering that double precision is now common on newest GPUs?

Comment: Double-precision is actually not "common." The latest hardware supports it, but short of GPGPU applications it is has no immediate use. It literally doubles storage requirements, which means a `dvec4` takes twice as many vertex attrib slots as `vec4`, for instance. You run out of resources, both memory and GLSL implementation limit wise, much quicker if you use double-precision. You also cannot sample textures at double-precision among other things. Only *part* of the pipeline supports double-precision, and it is mostly the part that crunches numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The opposite is the case. You should be using `float` by default in C++ and only use `double` if you are positively sure that you really need those extra digits of precision (for some scientific, presumably astronomic or particle physics, simulation). Often when you think you need `double`, you should be using fixed-point, or you should get your `float` values into the correct range.

You do **not** use double precision for graphics. Although all modern GPUs support it just fine, double precision math is often slower than single precision, and it has no observable advantage. Everything related to "graphics" (or let's say 99.99% since "everything" is a very definite wording) works just fine using `float` or `GLfloat` for that matter.
Even some years ago when some GPUs worked with only 24-bit precision, there was no visible difference.

In fact, when people use `double` because they *think* they should, then 99% of the time they are doing it wrong.

Tom Forsyth even made "double precision" the first point of his [Offend-O-Matic](http://home.comcast.net/~tom_forsyth/blog.wiki.html#OffendOMatic). He relates specifically to "games" but it really applies to almost every software, with some scientific simulations being the exception. Be sure to also read the accompanying article [A Matter of Precision](http://home.comcast.net/~tom_forsyth/blog.wiki.html#%5b%5bA%20matter%20of%20precision%5d%5d) to understand his reasoning.
A less offensive must-read on floating point is Ericson's [epsilon is not 0.000001](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/pubs/GDC05_Ericson_Numerical_Robustness_for_Geometric_Calculations.ppt) presentation.

It is very similar in OpenGL. If you understand how floating point works and use it correctly, then `float` will work just fine. The rounding errors when applying a transform matrix or such are not visible.
If you don't understand how it works, using double precision will shift the problems backwards a bit, but it will still bite you when you don't expect it.

Stunningly, even nowadays people still use double precision floating point even for absurd causes like currency or time (because it's *twice as much precise*, eh?) and are surprised when it blows up in their face and people start yelling at them.

Comment: "double precision math is often slower than single precision, and it has no observable advantage". Are you sure about that? At least give more details because it seems just plain wrong in the general case.

Comment: @Korchkidu: See for example [this](http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/150557). Also, using `GLdouble` e.g. for vertex attributes will literally double PCIe bandwidth requirements and cache pressure. The on-screen result is the same, however (as proven by early AMD implementations that used only 24-bit precision and that worked just fine nevertheless).

Comment: Your example is about GPU. But in the general case (C++ on CPU), I only heard the opposite double > float. For GPU and GLfloat/Gldouble I don't know, that's why I am asking. It seems that GLfloat > Gldouble then.

Comment: For C++ code running on a CPU, the performance hit is less pronounced. Many CPUs (for example x86) do math in double or extended double precision anyway -- they only store less information in RAM. But you still have double the storage size for double precision, which effectively halves the number of cache hits as compared to using single precision and doubles the memory bandwidth taken. However, to most people, it has no real advantage. It has a number of nasty pitfalls that aren't obvious to the casual person, however.

Comment: The idea of `float` is somewhat like this: You're measuring the size of your table (roughly 1.5 meters) and use integer fixed point for that. You decide for some arbitrary, easy-to-code scale of 128 = 1cm. So your table has a size of 19200. Your chosen scale allows you to measure any object up to around 335 kilometers with a precision of better than 1/10th millimeter. 1/10th mm is more precise than you can work as a typical self-thought craftsman, so all is good, and you will rarely have to construct a shelf that is bigger than 335 km either. Then your wife comes and wants you to measure ...

Comment: ... the distance to some far away city, let's say Tokyo (which is roughly 9,000 kilometers in my case). Darn, that doesn't fit. Now some smart person tells you that actually you don't need 1/10mm precision for that distance. Nobody cares, and nobody can tell the difference between 9,000 and 9,001 kilometers. Both are pretty far away, and it doesn't really matter. On the other hand, if you are doing some very fine engraving work, you don't need to be able to measure 300 kilometers, do you. Actually it would be nice if you could instead measure 1/10000 of a millimeter.

Comment: Again, you agree. Until one day, your wife wants you to calculate the distance from Tokyo to Yokohama. You know they're both roughly 9,000 kilometers away (you've measured that before). So you subtract one distance from the other and you see that the distance is zero. Darn, what now? So you send a drone which is armed with a long measuring tape to measure the distance. You tell it in coordinates centered at your position where to go. You test it in your garden, and it works fine. So you send it 9,000km away and _suddenly it stops working_. Grrr... what now.

Comment: Using `double` instead is the exact same thing, except you have a few more bits at hand and the failure appears later. But it does appear. Sometimes that is acceptable, sometimes "approximately" is just good enough, and sometimes "approximately but with a few more bits" is what you need. But that's rare.

Comment: Table, wife, Tokyo, drone, garden... seriously?;-D but I understood that it is better to use GLfloat than GLdouble in the general case. Thanks.